# ERROR: missing data for column XXX, SQLState: 22P04 (bad_copy_file_format)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL `COPY FROM` / `COPY TO` command to move data from my production environment table to my development environment table (they have the same structure, constraints, etc). I export my data using `COPY TO` command and that's OK, but problem occurs where I try to import that data using `COPY FROM`. I get an error:

> ERROR: missing data for column XXX, SQLState:  22P04 (bad_copy_file_format).

Both, production and development environment, are on the same machine running on Win XP SP3, PostgreSQL 8.3.

Command:

```
COPY table_name
TO 'C:/copy_export/table_name_export.csv'
WITH NULL as '\N'
delimiter ','
CSV
QUOTE  AS '\''
FORCE QUOTE col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Comment: Add the exact syntax for the commands you are using to your question.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use USING DELIMITERS ',' in my COPY FROM statement!!!! I'm down-voting my question :)